# How to add %custom-taxonomy% to permalink (e.g. %subject% which is one we created)

Tags: wordpress, permalinks, custom-taxonomy

I know there have been answers about similar questions, but it seems that these discuss about custom posts and custom taxonomies, but all I need is to be able to customise the URL so it incorporates the custom taxonomy like how you can add the category to the permalink. So the URL would be www.reviseshare.co.uk/(custom-taxonomy1)/(custom-taxonomy2)/(custom-taxonomy3)/(post-name). Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have already tried Beautiful Taxonomy Filters plugin, but it is not working as it doesn't even recognise my custom taxonomies created using pods.

Answer (score 0):

you can use my Wordpress plugin: Permalink Manager Lite to add custom taxonomies slugs to post permalinks.

After you install it, please go to **Tools -> Permalink Manager -> Permastructures** admin section and change the post permalinks format to:

`%custom_taxonomy_1%/%custom_taxonomy_2%/%custom_taxonomy_3%/%postname%`

After that you will need to regenerate the post permalinks in **Tools -> Permalink Manager -> Tools -> Regenerate/reset** section.

Comment: Thank you so much Maciej Bis

Comment: You are welcome. You can also find the more detailed instructions here:
https://permalinkmanager.pro/docs/tutorials/taxonomy-slugs-in-custom-post-type-permalinks/